# What's the best place to open a vortex

Tags: supernatural, paranormal

First off, a little background. This is inspired by the podcast [Welcome to Night Vale](https://open.spotify.com/show/0s6Wc5qf8SIvCtKZNC6N7s).

In a forest, a portal opened up to let out several paranormal creatures. After a year of spreading out, they went into aggressive mode. Several hundred people died. The first creature that was discovered was a large wolf with extreme speed and strength.

A few facts about this portal;

- It produces a very low amount of radiation.
- It must be in a forest (or someplace that can hide a portal).
- It must be in North America (Canada or America).
- This is in modern-day (no Covid).
- It has a bright black color.
- It has a low-frequency vibration.
- It is about 6ft high and 5 ft long

Facts about the creature:

- The creatures don't need food, sleep, air, or water.
- They are tough to kill (just strong enough that they will just barely survive a drop from space (62 miles)).
- Each has special abilities.
- When they die, they disappear.

So, where is the best place for this to open up and not be discovered?

If you have any questions, please ask. I will answer it. I can provide some information about the creatures if asked (there's more than one kind of monster).

Comment: They are discovered almost immediately as they start killing. Yes, they get tired, but it takes a while and a lot of movement. It is a little faster than a cheetah.

Comment: Oh come on. Any deep basement will do. Say the bottom level of an underground parking garage that is currently closed.

Comment: Can you expound on "bright black"? Does that mean like glossy/reflective black like obsidian?

Comment: How big is this portal?  If it's the size of a kiddie pool or something, then you could put it practically anywhere.  If it's the size of a skyscraper, there's almost nowhere you could put it.

Comment: Will comment more once my mind stops boggling at "Bright Black"

Comment: What I mean is, that the portal is a glowing black.

Comment: "Glowing black" isn't better than "bright black". Black is defined by the lack of light, which is required for both glowing and brightness. Do you perhaps mean a light-absorbing aura of fog being emitted?

Comment: Ok. Which is weirder: a portal to another realm, letting loose nearly invincible wolves, or a bright black. But this is not supposed to make sense. But somebody asked so I answered.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

#### Mammoth Cave National Park

[image]

A dark portal is going to stand out in the forest in the daytime, so to maximize time until discovery, put it somewhere in the [world's longest known cave system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mammoth_Cave_National_Park#Geology).  Several miles of new connections are discovered each year, so who knows what else might be lurking in the dark?

With [two million visitors](https://www.doi.gov/blog/mammoth-cave-explore-worlds-longest-cave) each year, it'll take a while to notice a few stragglers here or there.  Tight spaces, drop-offs, low ceilings and poor lighting all work to your creatures' advantage, and a few ghost stories will only add to the caves' mystique and tourist draw.

Since they won't starve en route, they can leave through any of the hundreds of entrances.  With high overland speeds they'll easily reach and spread throughout the wilderness of Kentucky, Tennessee, Indiana, and likely the other surrounding states.

Comment: very obvious why so many people visit, its absolutely stunning.

Comment: I considered this but it doesn't really meet "in a forest" very well.

Comment: @LorenPechtel The cave system is in a forest.  I'm fudging it a little bit, but  it felt like too good a site to pass up

Comment: I've been there. It's really cool (also literally: 58° F year round).

Answer (score 16):

**Canada**

Some 80% of Canadian land is uninhabited. 90% of Canadians live within 100 miles of the US border. Among countries, Canada ranks #2 in terms of land area, but #185 in terms of population density. There is plenty of space in Canada that's heavily forested and very sparsely populated, so you have a huge swath of land in which to hide the portal. Make it far from any settlements and useful bodies of water, and put it in an inhospitable location, far north and up a steep mountain or at the bottom of a cave/crevasse. With millions of square miles that don't have any permanent population centers, it would not strain credulity to hide something so anomalous that remained undiscovered for many years.

From the maps below, you can see there is plenty of land in Canada which is both heavily forested and sparsely populated. The Yukon/Northwest Territories region might be a good spot to hide, as there are only a few tens of thousands of people who live outside the major cities, spread over hundreds of thousands of square miles. Hiding almost anywhere in the dark green/grey regions of the maps would be reasonably plausible, though - Canada has a lot of land and few people.

[image: Canadian forests (Power and Gillis 2006)]
[image: Population density of Canada (Martel and Caron Malenfant 2007)]

Answer (score 7):

I know this might be a stretch of the "in a forest" requirement but,

**In an unexplored cave in Canada**

Deep in a forest you have a cave like [this](https://www.adventure-journal.com/2018/12/colossal-and-unexplored-mystery-cave-found-in-canada/) which has the portal trapping the wolves. Eventually, the cave fills up with enough nearly-immortal wolves with special abilities that they overflow out of the cave and begin the wolf massacre.

At 3 feet long and 3 feet tall and about 1 ft wide, lets say they only occupy half the space so about 4.5 cubic feet. If the cave is about half a cubic mile, then thats 73.6 million cubic feet of cave. To fill it up in a year, thats 44,809,741 wolves a day or 1,867,072 wolves an hour or 31,117 wolves a minute. Come to think of it, this cave should probably be much smaller. I don't want to die to a literal wolf cannon portal.

Lets drop it down to 1 wolf a minute. much more manageable. The cave would have to be 2,365,200 cubic feet. (1 wolf x 60 minutes x 24 hours x 365 days x 4.5 cubic feet per wolf) Simply place The Wolf Cave (tm) and wait for murder.

Comment: Thank you. This made me laugh a lot.

Answer (score 5):

Define "in a forest".

I'm picturing a rock overhang maybe 20' up, there's a cave extending into the overhang--the cave is vertical.  What's not apparent from the ground is that it widens a bit, the portal is in this widened area so no line of sight extends between any point of the portal and any point outside the cave.

The emerging monsters fall down, but you said they're tough to kill, I would figure they could take the drop.  This overhang could be in a forest, I don't know if that meets your definition of "in a forest".

As for where--there are large areas of mountainous, forested terrain in the Rocky Mountains.  I'd say most any steep area between 7,000' and 10,000' elevation in the Rockies would suffice, the remoter the better, but avoid protected lands (where there will be more hikers and backpackers.)  The overhang I'm picturing will not be common but that's a detail that isn't going to show up on any map, it would be perfectly reasonable to handwave it into anyplace steep enough.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, they can survive the drop. According to how strong I've made these, they might barely just survive a drop from space.

Answer (score 3):

**Underwater**
You defined "best" as "not be discovered".  Also, there is nothing in your description to suggest that it can't be immersed in a liquid.  You said that it must be in a forest, but then added a caveat as "(or someplace that wouldn't be discovered)".  Even if you want it in a forest, you could put it underwater in or near that forest.

You said your creatures don't need air, so put it at the bottom of a lake, in a river, or even in the ocean.  In fact, the deeper the better - it's really difficult for us to explore the ocean bottom.  Lakes are often murky and likewise difficult to explore.

Answer (score 1):

Does it really have to be in a forest, or just somewhere hard to discover? Here are some options that come to mind:

- Inside a hollowed out redwood tree
- Abandoned mine
- Active mine, resulting in a poor fate for miners, possibly a cave in, and possibly trouble for the rescue crew
- Abandoned missile silo from the cold war
- Behind a waterfall
- On the set of the next season of Stranger Things. (It will take a while before the crew realizes its not some bleeding edge AR experience.)
- Abandoned blimp hangar (these things are huge)
- Centralia
- Former above ground nuclear test site / mock town
- Former underground nuclear test site
- Abandoned cold war bomb shelter